# Increase size of Lightning Component to fit properly on a record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, lightning-design-system, html

[image]

The component I created on the right appears smaller than the activity card. I've tried several ways to increase it's size but have failed. Is there a way to make it look like the card below it?

Component code:

```
<div class="tabset slds-tabs_card uiTabset--base uiTabset--default uiTabset--dense uiTabset flexipageTabset" data-aura-rendered-by="533:0" data-aura-class="uiTabset--base uiTabset--default uiTabset--dense uiTabset flexipageTabset">
                <ul class="slds-box">
                    <li class="buttonPadding"><lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand"
                                          label="Signature"
                                          title="Signature"
                                          onclick="{! c.openModelSignature }" />
                    </li>
                    <li class="buttonPadding"><lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand"
                                          label="Additional Owner Info"
                                          title="Additional Owner Info"
                                          onclick="{! c.openModelAddnInfo }" />
                    </li>
                    <li class="buttonPadding"> <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand"
                                           label="Personal Guarantee"
                                           title="Personal Guarantee"
                                           onclick="{! c.openModelPersonalGuarantee }" />
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```

Comment: normally, you want to ensure that the component's parent (the container) has the proper sizing, its not clear if the above is a custom layout page or the OOTB one. Also, do you happen to have a css file with your component, can you share it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using deprecated/removed SLDS. You'll want to check the documentation for the new versions (generally `--` has been replaced with `_`). Also, `slds-box` produces a box that's no larger than necessary. Consider using lightning:tab, lightning:tabset, and probably lightning:card if you're trying to build something that looks standard.